# SSL in production server using docker-compose and a dockerised apache2

Tags: apache, docker, ssl, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose production environment that comprises 4 different services running in an AWS ec2 instance. Everything is running fine, and one of the services is exposed to the world via mapping the internal private ip address to ec2's public ip address.The exposed service is a laravel-vue.js app running in an apache2 server using the image

> FROM php:7.2-apache

and some custom commands below. My employer now bought a domain (not from Amazon route 53 but a different provider) and I want to get an ssl certificate for said domain and use it in my apache server. I have never put an ssl certificate before but i kind of understand the theory. My first step was to redirect the domain name from the provider to the public IP address. Now the app is accessible from the domain name via http instead of visiting an ip address.

I'm not sure what the next step should be. Can I get any ssl certificate e.g. from [let's encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) or [digicert](https://www.digicert.com/) and place it in my apache server?Would the ssl work only if issued from the domain provider? In my service, would I only have to  change the configuration to allow traffic through ssl and I'm done? My apache server doesn't do any dns, it simply exposes a webroot to port 80 and my docker-compose file forwards that ip address so that it becomes accessible to the world.Do I need to change apache dns settings and include the domain name?

This is my relevant docker-compose file part:

```
app:
 ports:
   - "172:31.31.159:80:80"
 build:
   context: .
   dockerfile: app/Dockerfile
 stdin_open: true
 environment:
  APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT: /var/www/html/public
 depends_on:
  - api
  - app-db
```

And here is the dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

COPY /app /var/www/html
WORKDIR /var/www/html

ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html/public
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf


# update apt-get
RUN apt-get update

# install the required components
RUN apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev g++ libicu-dev libmcrypt4 zlib1g-dev git libpq-dev libmagickwand-dev
RUN apt-get install zip unzip
# install the PHP extensions we need
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

#RUN apt-get install php-zip
# delete the lists for apt-get as the take up space we do not need.
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# install composer globally so that you can call composer directly
RUN curl -sSL https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
RUN mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
RUN composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev

# enable apache rewrite
RUN a2enmod rewrite


RUN service apache2 restart

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gnupg && \
    curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash - && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs && \
    npm install -g npm

RUN npm install
RUN npm audit fix
RUN npm run production
# set www permissions
RUN chown -R www-data:1001 .
RUN usermod -u 1001 www-data

RUN php artisan config:cache
```

Feel free to call out any problems with the dockerfile or docker-compose files as this is my first time using them for production.

Comment: You have a ton of options here, many quick and dirty, and other a bit more long and less hacky. do you want to get it done quick or done well?

Comment: `Can I get any ssl certificate e.g. from let's encrypt or digicert and place it in my apache server?` yeah `Would the ssl work only if issued from the domain provider? `  no, your could even issue it from your local machine `In my service, would I only have to change the configuration to allow traffic through ssl and I'm done? ` yeah `Do I need to change apache dns settings and include the domain name?` you need to be in control of the domain name

Comment: Short answer: I'd like to know both options for learning purposes :) Long answer: We're going to go live mid September so I have a month to play with this. I'd like to do it well but if I can't make it then quick and hacky will do as it's only a beta testing version

Comment: Thanks - What do you mean I need to be in control of the domain name? I do have power of the dns settings of the domain name or rather my employer does, anything else I should be watching out for?. Which solution would you recommend then? This is a case where i'd like to get the job done and over but I'd like to avoid repeating the question in the future, so how do you categorise which one is dirty and hacky and which one's done well

Comment: if you want to use let's encrypt, without doing any change/work/setup on what you currently have, run certbot https://hub.docker.com/r/certbot/certbot/ and generate the certificate manually using the dns challenge `certbot certonly --manual -d yourdomain.com --agree-tos --manual-public-ip-logging-ok --preferred-challenges dns-01` -> this assume that you can add TXT record in the dns settings of such domain. once the challenge is complete, you got a certificate and private key that you can bundle in the apache configuration; https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/ provide example of such config

Comment: issue with this approach is that this process is not automated, and you don't really want to do this each 3 months

Comment: Thanks. What is the right approach for that then? Something a bit more long term

Comment: a better option is to have another container to do this whole "generate certificates, renew certificate, etc"; apache would forward certain requests to this container ( which is probably just certbot ), and allow certbot to complete the http challenge

Comment: something along the line of https://medium.com/@pentacent/nginx-and-lets-encrypt-with-docker-in-less-than-5-minutes-b4b8a60d3a71 ( same would work for apache )

Comment: but, there are some many options here; https://github.com/JrCs/docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion is also an option; if you are on k8s, cert-manager is another, and more